# How to Convert HTTP Response XML Document into object in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, object, http-response-codes

I want to convert HTTP Response XML document into object.

When I tried to Deserialize I am getting Error like

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: There is an error in XML document (1, 2).

Here is my Class File

```
namespace Salcomp.SerialNumberStatus
{
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class OperationTypes
{

    private List<OperationType> operationTypeField;

    private static System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer;

    public OperationTypes()
    {
        this.operationTypeField = new List<OperationType>();
    }

    public List<OperationType> OperationType
    {
        get
        {
            return this.operationTypeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.operationTypeField = value;
        }
    }

    private static System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer Serializer
    {
        get
        {
            if ((serializer == null))
            {
                serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(OperationTypes));
            }
            return serializer;
        }
    }

    #region Serialize/Deserialize
    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes current OperationTypes object into an XML document
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>string XML value</returns>
    public virtual string Serialize()
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = null;
        System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
        try
        {
            memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            Serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, this);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
            streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(memoryStream);
            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        finally
        {
            if ((streamReader != null))
            {
                streamReader.Dispose();
            }
            if ((memoryStream != null))
            {
                memoryStream.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes workflow markup into an OperationTypes object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xml">string workflow markup to deserialize</param>
    /// <param name="obj">Output OperationTypes object</param>
    /// <param name="exception">output Exception value if deserialize failed</param>
    /// <returns>true if this XmlSerializer can deserialize the object; otherwise, false</returns>
    public static bool Deserialize(string xml, out OperationTypes obj, out System.Exception exception)
    {
        exception = null;
        obj = default(OperationTypes);
        try
        {
            obj = Deserialize(xml);
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            exception = ex;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static bool Deserialize(string xml, out OperationTypes obj)
    {
        System.Exception exception = null;
        return Deserialize(xml, out obj, out exception);
    }

    public static OperationTypes Deserialize(string xml)
    {
        System.IO.StringReader stringReader = null;
        try
        {
            stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(xml);
            return ((OperationTypes)(Serializer.Deserialize(System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stringReader))));
        }
        finally
        {
            if ((stringReader != null))
            {
                stringReader.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes current OperationTypes object into file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName">full path of outupt xml file</param>
    /// <param name="exception">output Exception value if failed</param>
    /// <returns>true if can serialize and save into file; otherwise, false</returns>
    public virtual bool SaveToFile(string fileName, out System.Exception exception)
    {
        exception = null;
        try
        {
            SaveToFile(fileName);
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            exception = e;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public virtual void SaveToFile(string fileName)
    {
        System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter = null;
        try
        {
            string xmlString = Serialize();
            System.IO.FileInfo xmlFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileName);
            streamWriter = xmlFile.CreateText();
            streamWriter.WriteLine(xmlString);
            streamWriter.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            if ((streamWriter != null))
            {
                streamWriter.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes xml markup from file into an OperationTypes object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName">string xml file to load and deserialize</param>
    /// <param name="obj">Output OperationTypes object</param>
    /// <param name="exception">output Exception value if deserialize failed</param>
    /// <returns>true if this XmlSerializer can deserialize the object; otherwise, false</returns>
    public static bool LoadFromFile(string fileName, out OperationTypes obj, out System.Exception exception)
    {
        exception = null;
        obj = default(OperationTypes);
        try
        {
            obj = LoadFromFile(fileName);
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            exception = ex;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static bool LoadFromFile(string fileName, out OperationTypes obj)
    {
        System.Exception exception = null;
        return LoadFromFile(fileName, out obj, out exception);
    }

    public static OperationTypes LoadFromFile(string fileName)
    {
        System.IO.FileStream file = null;
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = null;
        try
        {
            file = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(file);
            string xmlString = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
            file.Close();
            return Deserialize(xmlString);
        }
        finally
        {
            if ((file != null))
            {
                file.Dispose();
            }
            if ((sr != null))
            {
                sr.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}

public partial class OperationType
{

    private string uriField;

    private string nameField;

    private string numberField;

    private bool activeField;

    private bool activeFieldSpecified;

    private string descriptionField;

    private OperationSetupCalculation setupCalculationField;

    private bool setupCalculationFieldSpecified;

    private string sideField;

    private bool usedForRoutingField;

    private bool usedForSchedulingField;

    private string categoryField;

    private string skillsField;

    private string aaa;

    private static System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer;

    public OperationType()
    {
        this.usedForRoutingField = false;
        this.usedForSchedulingField = false;
    }

    public string Uri
    {
        get
        {
            return this.uriField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.uriField = value;
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }

    public string Number
    {
        get
        {
            return this.numberField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.numberField = value;
        }
    }

    public bool Active
    {
        get
        {
            return this.activeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.activeField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool ActiveSpecified
    {
        get
        {
            return this.activeFieldSpecified;
        }
        set
        {
            this.activeFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return this.descriptionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.descriptionField = value;
        }
    }

    public OperationSetupCalculation SetupCalculation
    {
        get
        {
            return this.setupCalculationField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.setupCalculationField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool SetupCalculationSpecified
    {
        get
        {
            return this.setupCalculationFieldSpecified;
        }
        set
        {
            this.setupCalculationFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    public string Side
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sideField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sideField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute(false)]
    public bool UsedForRouting
    {
        get
        {
            return this.usedForRoutingField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.usedForRoutingField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute(false)]
    public bool UsedForScheduling
    {
        get
        {
            return this.usedForSchedulingField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.usedForSchedulingField = value;
        }
    }

    public string Category
    {
        get
        {
            return this.categoryField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.categoryField = value;
        }
    }

    public string Skills
    {
        get
        {
            return this.skillsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.skillsField = value;
        }
    }

    private static System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer Serializer
    {
        get
        {
            if ((serializer == null))
            {
                serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(OperationType));
            }
            return serializer;
        }
    }

    #region Serialize/Deserialize
    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes current OperationType object into an XML document
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>string XML value</returns>
    public virtual string Serialize()
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = null;
        System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
        try
        {
            memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            Serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, this);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
            streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(memoryStream);
            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        finally
        {
            if ((streamReader != null))
            {
                streamReader.Dispose();
            }
            if ((memoryStream != null))
            {
                memoryStream.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes workflow markup into an OperationType object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xml">string workflow markup to deserialize</param>
    /// <param name="obj">Output OperationType object</param>
    /// <param name="exception">output Exception value if deserialize failed</param>
    /// <returns>true if this XmlSerializer can deserialize the object; otherwise, false</returns>
    public static bool Deserialize(string xml, out OperationType obj, out System.Exception exception)
    {
        exception = null;
        obj = default(OperationType);
        try
        {
            obj = Deserialize(xml);
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            exception = ex;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static bool Deserialize(string xml, out OperationType obj)
    {
        System.Exception exception = null;
        return Deserialize(xml, out obj, out exception);
    }

    public static OperationType Deserialize(string xml)
    {
        System.IO.StringReader stringReader = null;
        try
        {
            stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(xml);
            return ((OperationType)(Serializer.Deserialize(System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stringReader))));
        }
        finally
        {
            if ((stringReader != null))
            {
                stringReader.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes current OperationType object into file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName">full path of outupt xml file</param>
    /// <param name="exception">output Exception value if failed</param>
    /// <returns>true if can serialize and save into file; otherwise, false</returns>
    public virtual bool SaveToFile(string fileName, out System.Exception exception)
    {
        exception = null;
        try
        {
            SaveToFile(fileName);
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            exception = e;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public virtual void SaveToFile(string fileName)
    {
        System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter = null;
        try
        {
            string xmlString = Serialize();
            System.IO.FileInfo xmlFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileName);
            streamWriter = xmlFile.CreateText();
            streamWriter.WriteLine(xmlString);
            streamWriter.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            if ((streamWriter != null))
            {
                streamWriter.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes xml markup from file into an OperationType object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName">string xml file to load and deserialize</param>
    /// <param name="obj">Output OperationType object</param>
    /// <param name="exception">output Exception value if deserialize failed</param>
    /// <returns>true if this XmlSerializer can deserialize the object; otherwise, false</returns>
    public static bool LoadFromFile(string fileName, out OperationType obj, out System.Exception exception)
    {
        exception = null;
        obj = default(OperationType);
        try
        {
            obj = LoadFromFile(fileName);
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            exception = ex;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static bool LoadFromFile(string fileName, out OperationType obj)
    {
        System.Exception exception = null;
        return LoadFromFile(fileName, out obj, out exception);
    }

    public static OperationType LoadFromFile(string fileName)
    {
        System.IO.FileStream file = null;
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = null;
        try
        {
            file = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(file);
            string xmlString = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
            file.Close();
            return Deserialize(xmlString);
        }
        finally
        {
            if ((file != null))
            {
                file.Dispose();
            }
            if ((sr != null))
            {
                sr.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Another File:

```
    namespace Salcomp.SerialNumberStatus
    {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        MasterDataManagement MDM = new MasterDataManagement("http://localhost:8012/");
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            Salcomp.SerialNumberStatus.OperationType operationType = new Salcomp.SerialNumberStatus.OperationType();

           var test =  MDM.RestGet<Salcomp.SerialNumberStatus.OperationType>("http://localhost/Enterprise/OperationTypes");

        }
    }
}
```

Deserialize

```
public T RestGet<T>(string url)
    {
        if (!url.Contains("http://")) url = _mdmServerUrl + url;
        var xDoc = url.HttpGet();
        var xml = xDoc.ToString();
        return XmlDeserializeFromString<T>(xml);
    }

    private T XmlDeserializeFromString<T>( string objectData)
    {
        return (T)XmlDeserializeFromString(objectData, typeof(T));
    }

    private  object XmlDeserializeFromString( string objectData, Type type)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
        object result;

        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(objectData))
        {
            result = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

XML Response:

```
<OperationTypes xmlns="http://www.example.com/aaa/2011" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <OperationType Uri="http://localhost:8012/Enterprise/OperationTypes/a1d02dac-c454-497b-808d-a619009c7c7e" Name="test" Number="19" Active="true" Description="" SetupCalculation="PerWorkOrder" Side="" />
<OperationType Uri="http://localhost:8012/Enterprise/OperationTypes/07102c89-93e1-499b-980e-a61900cf2217" Name="OT_Prakash" Number="20" Active="false" Description="" SetupCalculation="PerWorkOrder" Side="" />
</OperationTypes>
```

I have tried many answers in stackoverflow but I am not able to get it.

any help appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that problem is because of encoding and/or BOM (Byte Order Mask) at the start of the XML.

One problem is that your XML output is missing XML header together with encoding information. I think it falls back to UTF-8.

At the same time .NET by default uses UTF-16 encoding and when writing to stream/file adds BOM. BOM makes XML parser to blow up.

Please check your XML file with some HEX editor and ensure that there are no unexpected invisible symbols at the start of the XML.

Here is sample XML serizalization/deserialization code that I have used. It should always produce XML file with UTF-8 encoding without BOM. Also, it should work even if there is BOM or some other junk before XML header.

```
public class XmlDataSerializer
{
    public string Serialize<T>(T objectValue) where T : class
    {
        var utf8WithoutBom = new UTF8Encoding(false);
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        var xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            Indent = true,
            Encoding = utf8WithoutBom
        };

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, xmlWriterSettings))
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, objectValue);
                return utf8WithoutBom.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }

    public T Deserialize<T>(string stringValue) where T : class
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        //hacky way to get rid of BOM for all encodings
        var xmlStart = stringValue.IndexOf("<?xml", StringComparison.Ordinal);
        if (xmlStart > 0)
        {
            stringValue = stringValue.Remove(0, xmlStart);
        }

        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(stringValue))
        {
            using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
            {
                return xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader) as T;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have tried added XML Header tag manually , still i get the same error There is an error in XML document (1, 41).so i removed **xmlns="---"** now the above error is not coming but converted object properties are not having any values from XML file.

Comment: ,can you please give some advice.

Comment: I have added sample code. It does not necessary show best practices, but it should work for your scenario. Code should be easily adjustable to fit your existing code. Also, you should consider separating entity code from serialization because serialization should not be baked in the object as it might change over time, for example, at some point you might want to switch to JSON.

Comment: Thanks Kaspars , i will give it try.